# Is it possible to save data temporarily on runtime of java GUI application without having any database functionality?

Tags: java, user-interface

I want to make a library management system in which I want to store book name and book ID etc. But I am restricted not to use the database functionality and save that data only during the time of execution.

How could I go about this?

Comment: I appreciate the quick comeback!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your options are straight forward:

- keep that data in memory
- use a temporary file in the file system
- connect to some remote service where your app stores data (and then you are free to use whatever persistence mechanism you like to use)

Comment: In this case I answer with Guten abend ! A true patriot, I like that ! You are in good shape, great ! Triple X is also great. It makes me to think of the Wrestler of the WWE : Triple H ! Well I stop. So my question is there : I have a very comfortable chair at my work. That is German. The brand is König Neurath. So first thing, do you know this brand ? I

Comment: @davidxxx I remember triple h while he was still called hunter Hearst helmsley and mostly got beaten up and thrown around. I don't know that company, but their chairs look impressive. And expensive.

Comment: I even didn't know that. On SO, we learn really many things  : even on Wrestle ! These don't look only. Really great. Try it if you can one day.  I would like your mind about one of these models, you are definitively not the right person... But If I have a question on a wrestler, sure I will think of you ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Some type of storage medium needs to be decided on. There are a couple choices you can use. You can store the data as property files, xml or json.

There are tools like Jackson that can serialize and deserialize objects to json files and POJOs respectively to make persistence easier. There are also tools for xml and property file as well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, 2 quick ways that come to my mind right now are (if you are not using database):

1) use filing (searching and update could be harder)

2) user data structures - in memory storage (select the flexible data structure, storing data objects in array list would be easy but again depends on your requirements and nature of data)